# Missing SimpleJson Module

Tags: python, ansible

I have Ansible playbook run against a machine with CentOS release 5.6 (Final).
I have simplejson installed in the target machine and the module is importable from the python interpreter.
But still my playbooks fails with the below error.

```
Error: ansible requires a json module, none found!
```

I am confirming the presence of the simple json module at runtime by a raw module as shown below.

```
--- 
- 
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: "{{ host_group }}"
  name: deploy
  vars_files:
    - "{{env}}.yml"
  tasks:
    - name: check python version
      raw: python -c "import simplejson"

    - name: "git checkout"
      git: "repo={{repository}} dest={{base_dir}} version={{branch}}"
```

The first step succeeds without any issue as shown below

```
TASK: [check python version] ************************************************** 
ok: [my-target-machine] => {"rc": 0, "stderr": "", "stdout": ""}
```

but the second fails with the above said error of missing json module.

Comment: Try to install `python-simplejson` module

Comment: @itzmeontv I have that module installed. python -c "import simplejson" succeeds

Comment: Ansible requires python-simplejson being installed on EL boxes < 6.

Comment: @itzmeontv should i have to install something other then simplejson module? I have already have simplejson module installed. if you see my first play its uses raw module and successfully imports the simplejson module.

Comment: if you are running less than Python 2.5 on the remotes, that need it as a dependency to run modules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible + 10.11.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799807/ansible-10-11-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be happening because you have two versions of python: the system python at `/usr/bin/python` and another python at perhaps `/usr/local/bin/python`. If the first-on-path python is >=2.5 or otherwise has simplejson in its site-packages, the first task would execute fine. However, if you've not installed simplejson for the system python at `/usr/bin/python` (easiest to just `sudo yum -y install python-simplejson`), then the `git` task could fail.

Standard ansible modules always use the `#!/usr/bin/python` shebang, and the [git module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/source_control/git.py) is no exception.

Also, from the [ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-python-pathing-not-having-a-python-2-x-in-usr-bin-python-on-a-remote-machine):

> By default Ansible assumes it can find a /usr/bin/python on your remote system that is a 2.X version of Python, specifically 2.4 or higher.
>
> Setting of an inventory variable ‘ansible_python_interpreter’ on any host will allow Ansible to auto-replace the interpreter used when executing python modules. Thus, you can point to any python you want on the system if /usr/bin/python on your system does not point to a Python 2.X interpreter.